# swift 3 ViewController to TableViewController

Tags: uitableview, swift3, uiviewcontroller

I'm building a todo list app. So far I have a tableViewController in which i have the list of todo created and when I click on it a viewcontroller opens with the content inside. I have a navigationController linked to the tableviewcontroller, and tableviewcontroller linked to viewcontroller.
What I want to do now is create a new viewcontroller with an input inside, you insert your name and after clicking on a button it opens the tableviewcontroller with the list inside.
Is is the same way as linking tableviewcontroller to viewcontroller or is there a difference ?

[EDIT]

Here's what I've got so far :

[image]

Comment: What user action will cause your new controller to be shown?

Comment: The user will click a button that will display the tableviewcontroller. I've edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you want a new view controller to pop up when clicking on create button. drop another view controller on your storyboard. Connect your button to that view controller using segue and set type as Present Modally. Now when you click on the button, the new view controller will show up.

Now add a button on the new view controller, connect to code using an IBAction. In the action, call `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` Now when you click on this button, your new view controller will be dismissed.

Finally, add your create new use stuff on your new view controller, and pass data back to your table view using unwind segue, which you can search on Google.

Your story board will look something like this

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make that viewcontroller the entry point of the application ? The tableView would be accesssible only if the user connects. And the button create is use to create a new row in the tableViewController, it's adding a todo

Comment: @SamCaneau  yes. Then simply add this view controller between navigation controller and table controller. Use push segue in this case

Answer (score 0):

1. you remove navigation bar in all controller than accepted action clicked event for viewing controller present.
2. your login view controller to table view  for applay push view controller code and back for pop view controller code apply.

3.you search in google table view to detail view you will get exact idea how to pass data tableview data to view controller in show data ...